# Setting An Org Heading Property From Yasnippet

Tags: org-mode, yasnippet

I have a yasnippet snippet for adding the boilerplate to my "daily review" org document. Here's what it looks like:

```
# key: ndr
# name: newdailyreview
# --
* Accomplishments
  :PROPERTIES:
 :CUSTOM_ID: accomplishments
  :END

  - $1

* Goals For Tomorrow
  :PROPERTIES:
 :CUSTOM_ID: goals
  :END

  - $2

* Observations
  :PROPERTIES:
 :CUSTOM_ID: observations
  :END

  $0
```

The problem is that when the property drawer is malformed when printed. I tried preserving white space by adding this at the top:

```
# expand-env: ((yas-indent-line 'fixed) (yas-wrap-around-region 'nil))
```

But that didn't make a difference. I then tried setting the property like this:

```
`(org-set-property "CUSTOM_ID" "report")`
```

Unfortunately, this actually changes the buffer, which I believe is a deprecated feature of yasnippet.

Is there another way to solve this problem?

Comment: I can't reproduce what you describe. I have yas-indent-line set to 'auto which seems to do the right thing. You are missing a : after END in the first block, and seem to be missing a space in front of the CUSTOM_ID, but even these are all corrected with 'auto for me.

Comment: Yes John, you are correct. The issue was with typos in my snippet. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Above John pointed out that the issue was with typos. Here's what ended up working:

```
# key: ndr
# name: newdailyreview
# expand-env: ((yas-indent-line 'auto) (yas-wrap-around-region 'nil))
# --
* Accomplishments
  :PROPERTIES:
  :CUSTOM_ID: accomplishments
  :END:

  - $1

* Goals For Tomorrow
  :PROPERTIES:
  :CUSTOM_ID: goals
  :END:

  - $2

* Observations
  :PROPERTIES:
  :CUSTOM_ID: observations
  :END:

  $0
```

Thanks again John!